# Allow hiding messages (or images) in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

There are rooms where posting animated GIF files is OK.

They are also annoying, more often than not. I wish I had another button in message UI which would collapse that message (or just the image(s) in that message).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137584/hide-or-collapse-individual-comments-in-chat